# Google Sign In Authentication return to new ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, google-signin

I am currently making an app in Xcode, which has a GoogleSignIn Button(which was created using cocoapods) for the user so that he/she can sign in through Google in my app. I was wondering if there was anything that could make it so that the user, after getting authenticated by Google in the sign in, could then be returned to a new ViewController, in which the user could then carry on in doing what they wish to do in the app. I have tried looking up many solutions, but I don't know how to go about in solving this problem. I would appreciate any help.

More Info:

I'm using Xcode Beta 8.2 and programming this app mainly in Swift.

Here is my current code for the Viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        setupGoogleButtons()
    }

    fileprivate func setupGoogleButtons() {
        //add google sign in button
        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)
        //custom google button
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        customButton.backgroundColor = .orange
        customButton.setTitle("Custom Google Sign In", for: .normal)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomGoogleSign), for: .touchUpInside)
        customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        view.addSubview(customButton)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    }

    func handleCustomGoogleSign() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

And AppDelegate File:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self


        return true
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
        let credentials = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
        })
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {



        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                          sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                          annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: @JoeC Thanks for the helpful information! I have edited my question, so that it meets the requirements on the checklist.